# Ansible vmware_vm_shell SED command adding extra characters

Tags: shell, sed, ansible, virtual-machine, vmware

I am having trouble getting this correct.

I gather the vm facts and have a test debug that gives me the correct mac address for the vm.  However when I add the query to a sed command I get extra characters added.

this works

```
- name: Get MAC address of VMs to add to eth0 configuration
  debug:
    msg: "{{ vm_guest_facts.results | json_query(s_query) }}"
  vars:
    s_query: "[?instance.hw_name == '{{ item }}'].instance.hw_eth0.macaddress"
  with_items: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

output

```
ok: [server1] => (item=server1) => {
    "msg": [
        "00:50:56:80:e0:a1"
    ]
```

this fails

```
- name: fix network phase 2 - replace template MAC
  vars:
    s_query: "[?instance.hw_name == '{{ item }}'].instance.hw_eth0.macaddress"
  vmware_vm_shell:
    hostname: '{{ deploy_vsphere_host }}'
    username: '{{ deploy_vsphere_user }}'
    password: '{{ deploy_vsphere_password }}'
    datacenter: "{{ vsphere_datacenter }}"
    validate_certs: no
    vm_id: "{{ item }}"
    vm_username: xxx
    vm_password: xxx
    vm_shell: '/bin/sed'
    vm_shell_args: " -i.bak 's/^HWADDR.*/HWADDR={{ vm_guest_facts.results | json_query(s_query) }}/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0"
  with_items:
    - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

output (snipped)

```
"vm_id": "server1", 
"vm_id_type": "vm_name", 
"vm_password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
"vm_shell": "/bin/sed", 
"vm_shell_args": " -i.bak 's/^HWADDR.*/HWADDR=[u'00:50:56:80:e0:a1']/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0", 
 "vm_shell_cwd": null, 
"vm_shell_env": null, 
"vm_username": "xxx", 
"wait_for_process": false
```

The mac address in the last line is getting the extra [u at the beginning and ] at the end.

Is there a way of fixing this or could someone help me with a sed line to remove those extra characters in an extra step.

Thanks,

Kane.

Answer (score 0):

Any task that is `with_items` always has a **list** of results, and you can see that in the `msg:` output containing the python **list** characters `[` and `]`. Thus, `vm_guest_facts.results | json_query()` needs either `[0]` or `| first` appended to it in order to resolve it to *one* thing

Comment: Thanks Matthew but I must be doing something wrong.

When I add to the query in vm_shell_args  | [0] all i get in the output is [ ] and | first tells me I have an undeclared variable.

Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up tried [0] in multiple places and multiple times.

Here is the cheat / dirty fix for this particular issue:

```
" -i.bak 's/^HWADDR.*/HWADDR={{ vm_guest_facts.results | json_query(s_query)| regex_replace(']') | regex_replace('\\[u') }}/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0"
```